# akka remote can't find

Tags: java, akka

I am learning Akka remoting, referring to the book *Learning Akka*.

Using a limited network, I can't use sbt (can't config the proxy well).

First, I create a project for an Akka server with the `application.conf`

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  remote {
    emabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
  }
}
```

and the console shows

```
Remoting now listens on addresses: [akka.tcp://akkademy@127.0.0.1:2552]
```

The second project is the client having a `JClient` class:

```
public class JClient {

    private static final int TIMEOUT = 2000;
    private final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("LocalSystem");
    private final ActorSelection remoteDb;

    public JClient(String remoteAddress) {
        remoteDb = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://LocalSystem@" + remoteAddress + "/user/akkademy-db");
    }

    public CompletionStage set(String key, Object value) {
        return toJava(ask(remoteDb, new SetRequest(key, value), TIMEOUT));
    }

    public CompletionStage<Object> get(String key) {
        return toJava(ask(remoteDb, new GetRequest(key), TIMEOUT));
    }    
}
```

I pass the value "127.0.0.1:2552" to `remoteAddress`, calling the `set`/`get` methods, and encounter the error:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://akkademy/deadLetters), Path(/user/.*)]] after [2000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type "javah.GetRequest".
```

Comment: I don't know why my remoteURI was converted to akka://akkademy/deadletters

Answer (score 0):

In `actorSelection` the selector should be string of format `akka.tcp://${remoteActorSystemName}@${remoteAddress}/user/$actorPath`. In the snippet you've posted, looks like you were using `LocalSystem` as `${remoteActorSystemName}` instead of the remote actor system name.

Let me know if switching it to remote works, if not, can you post the full code you are using or a link to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your client code to obtain an `ActorSelection` to the remote actor is incorrect. Instead of `"LocalSystem"`, which is the name of the client's actor system, use `"akkademy"`, the name of the server's actor system. Change the `JClient` constructor to the following:

```
public JClient(String remoteAddress) {
    remoteDb = system.actorSelection("akka.tcp://akkademy@" + remoteAddress + "/user/akkademy-db");
}
```